# 2 tone test with RF mixer

Tags: rf, mixer, non-linear

I am designing a system that uses RF to probe the nonlinearity of a target. It works as follows.

1. Transmitter sends out 2 RF frequencies, such as 900 and 910MHz.
2. The target/reflector has a nonlinearity, this causes the generation of 920MHz (among others).
3. The reflected signal (900+910+920) is received by an antenna, and mixed with 919.9MHz LO to generate a 100kHz signal that has amplitude proportional to the 920MHz signal. A low pass filter is applied to reject the higher frequencies.

My question is this: the input to the mixer is 900+910+920MHz. I only care about the 920MHz signal from the reflector in part 2. Will the 900+910 MHz that goes into the mixer be mixed and generate a huge 920MHz signal that swamps out the reflected 920MHz? What are your thoughts on this?

A key part of all this, is that I am hoping to avoid bandpass filtering at 920MHz before the mixer. I prefer to do this using the low pass at low frequency.

Comment: Yes, the mixer itself will have a 3rd-order intermodulation product at 920MHz (100kHz on the output).  The real question is will this be enough to cause problems?  You need to characterize your mixer and see -- if you hit it with your combination of 900 + 910, without your nonlinear material, and you see too much energy at 920MHz (or 100kHz on the output), then you know your setup is a non-starter.  Note that if you're trying to get really sensitive, you could also have mixing in the output stages of your two RF sources, or at any rusty junction in the room.

Comment: Note the strong dependence of 3IP on input level. Reducing the input signals by only 10dB (in a relatively crude filter) will reduce the 3rd order product by 30dB. Amd if you can reduce 910MHz by 10dB you may get a significantly higher attenuation at 900MHz. So don't rule out a front end bandpass filter as an option, unless you really like making life difficult.

Comment: I see, this really clarifies the problem. Thanks for your help!